# Multiple declaration error in data type declaration

Tags: haskell

I'm currently building a a Twitter CLI client in Haskell, and I have a data type that represents a DM and one that represents a tweet. However, I get a multiple declaration error because I have to use the same name for both:

```
data Users =  Users { screen_name :: String } deriving(Show, Generic)


data Tweet = Tweet { text :: !Text,
                     retweeted :: Bool,
                     user :: Users
                   } deriving (Show, Generic)

data DM = DM { text :: !Text,
               sender_screen_name :: String
             } deriving (Show, Generic)
```

Does someone know a solution for this particular problem?

Comment: either move it into different modules or rename them (`dm_text`, ...) - if you are on GHC 8 you can have a look at [DuplicateRecordFields](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Records/OverloadedRecordFields/DuplicateRecordFields) but personally I don't like this too much

Comment: The problem is that it has to match the api name , so it returns the information that i need , so dm_text is not gonna work . Im going to look at creating a module

Comment: well yes - but you always have the option to implement the JSON instances yourself - so the names won't matter (but modules are probably easier ;))

Answer (score 0):

As defined [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Name_clashes_in_record_fields), the named members are just functions that are used to call the values in your data structure.

So, if you really want to use them, you can do so by using the language extension. You can do that by declaring this in your file:

`{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}`